# Mongoose 5.x.x: Is 'new' required for creating a Schema?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

The Quick Start section of the documentation for Mongoose 5.0.15, including the main landing page of their website, shows no `new` keyword when creating a Schema. When I click on the Schemas section of the documentation, it shows the `new` keyword.

I am wondering if `new` is required or not in 5.x.x as the documentation is super inconsistent? It was used in 4.x.x.

Thanks

```
var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
})
```

**VS**

```
var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `new` is required because without that you'd just be calling the `Schema()` function, rather than construct a new instance of `Schema` (latter is what you actually need).

BUT if you look at the [source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7237444f826dd58816d02ba2214107cc61c17d45/lib/schema.js#L58) for schema.js, they return a new instance anyway, even if you call `Schema()` as a direct function (i.e. without `new`). So there would be no difference whether or not you use `new`. You get a new Schema object either way.